# print string with special characters

Tags: php, string

I have a string which is an output from an API.The string contains special characters as follows :

```
$stringFromTheApi = "Diljit\nis\na\n\t\ta\ngood\nbody";
```

How do I print the string with the special characters inside them,I tried doing print_r($string) but did not work?

Comment: convert `'`'s to `"`'s and if using html/css put them in a `pre` tag

Comment: [`stripcslashes()`](http://php.net/stripcslashes) perhaps.

Comment: @mario you did not understand the question I am afraid.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski No, and anticipating no further explanation I voted accordingly.

Comment: @mario Basically I am building an automated judge system .The string i am receiving from the API is exactly the same that I have stored in my datbase.Somewhat like expectedoutput == $outputfromAPi then your test cases passes,I tried printing both strings,they are exactly similar but the length of the former varies and I am still confused .So i wanted to print the string with the special characters inside them.any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes do not parse special chars. Use double quotes instead

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

> Double quoted
>
> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret
>   more escape sequences for special characters:
>
> Escaped characters Sequence   Meaning \n  linefeed (LF or 0x0A (10) in
>   ASCII) \r carriage return (CR or 0x0D (13) in ASCII)